# Saving Object's To Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, cocoa-touch

I have the following code that saves an object to a file...

```
-(int) saveObject: (id)object forKey: (NSString *) key 
{
    //save object into file

    NSLog(@"PRESENT");
    if(filePath == nil) 
    {
        [self setFilePath:nil];
    }

    mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if(mainDict == nil) 
    {
        mainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    [mainDict setObject:object forKey:key];

    if(![mainDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) 
    {
        return 2; //ERROR could not write object to file
        if(object == nil) {
            return 3;
        }
        if(key == nil) {
            return 4;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if(shouldUseCache == YES) {
            cacheStatus = 2; //New Caches need to be updated
        }
        return 1; //SUCCESS object saved to file
    }

    //RETURN KEY's
    // *1 SUCCESS object saved to file
    // *2 ERROR could not write object to file
    // *3 ERROR object variable = nil
    // *4 ERROR key variable = nil
}
```

As you can see the method should clearly return a number between 1 and 4 but when I call the method in my view controller I get 0???

The weirdest part is that I don't even receive the NSLog(@"Present") in my console???

What is the problem and what causes this???

Here is my simple view controller...

```
NSLog(@"%d",[mainDict saveObject:@"HELLO" forKey:@"foo"]);
```

My .h file as well...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ObjectSaver.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    ObjectSaver *mainDict;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that the `return 3` or `return 4` paths can be reached...

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely missing a closing brace `}` after `return 2;`...

Comment: That's correct. If it fails, it will always return 2. To fix this, you should move `return 2` after the 2 if statements for `return 3` and `return 4`

Comment: He's actually not missing the brace, he just put the returns in the wrong order. The closing brace is right before the `else`

Comment: @Dima Yeah, I just noticed that when I was reformatting the code to be more readable so I could see what was going on xD

Comment: **Question:** So when a method calls the return statment does the method end and not execute any more code?

Comment: @TheMan Yes, that is exactly what `return` does.

Comment: A higher level comment. Have your method return a BOOL instead of an int with YES for success and NO for failure. Then rewrite your method to take an reference to an NSError pointer. That way you can return NO in the failure cases and provide far more detail (and recovery options) in the NSError. This is the way the frameworks do it and is a more Objective-C way of dealing with methods that may not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to start: this statement doesn't do anything:

```
 if(filePath == nil) {
     [self setFilePath:nil]; }
```

If your NSLog isn't getting hit, then the function doesn't get called at all. Have you put a breakpoint into the function and debugged to see if it is actually ever entered?

Also as the comments say, your function will currently never `return 3` or `return 4`. For it to be able to do so, `return 2` should be moved after those 2 `if` blocks so that it can be the default error if the other 2 are not valid.

Comment: Good idea! I put the break point in the method and I found that my program never pauses... WHY????

Comment: Do you ever initialize ObjectSaver* mainDict?  If the object doesn't exist, methods cannot be called on it and the message will return 0.

Comment: Thanks WendiKidd! I didn't know you still had to alloc/ init an object declaired in the .h file...

Comment: @TheMan Yes, you do :)  Declaring it in the .h just gives it a name and a type--you still must alloc/init it to assign memory to its address :)  Also Dima's answer and the subsequence comments helped you, you should accept it :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help!